# Arbitrary host name resolution in Ansible

Tags: python, postgresql, sockets, ansible

Is there a way to resolve an arbitrary string as a host name in Ansible `group_vars` file or in a Jinja2 template used by Ansible? Let's say, I want to define a variable in `global_vars/all` that would contain one of the several IP addresses that `www.google.com` resolves into. In this example, I used `www.google.com` just as an example of a string that ca be resolved into multiple IP addresses and yet I cannot use Ansible `hostvars` for the address because I cannot ssh into it.

I tried to wire in Pythonic `socket.gethostbyname()` but could not get the syntax right. At most, my variable became a literal "socket.gethostbyname('my-host-1')".

I know I can fall back to a shell script and to take advantage of the tools available in shell but I'd like to see if there is an elegant way to accomplish this in Ansible.

The more gory details of the question are that I need to populate Postgres HBA configuration file with IP addresses of the permitted hosts. I cannot use their host names because the target deployment does not have reverse DNS that is required for host name based HBA.

I really wish Postgres resolved the names in the configuration file and matched it against the client's IP address instead of doing a reverse lookup of the client's IP address and then matching the strings of host names. But this is too much to expect and too long to wait. I need a workaround for now, and I'd like to stay within Ansible for that, not having to offload this into an external script.

Thank you for reading this far!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can create a lookup plugin for this:

**Ansible 1.x:**

```
import ansible.utils as utils
import ansible.errors as errors
import socket

class LookupModule(object):
    
    def __init__(self, basedir=None, **kwargs):
        self.basedir = basedir

    def run(self, terms, inject=None, **kwargs):
        
        if not isinstance(terms, basestring):
            raise errors.AnsibleError("ip lookup expects a string (hostname)")
        
        return [socket.gethostbyname(terms)]
```

**Ansible 2.x:**

```
import ansible.utils as utils
import ansible.errors as errors
from ansible.plugins.lookup import LookupBase
import socket

class LookupModule(LookupBase):
    
    def __init__(self, basedir=None, **kwargs):
        self.basedir = basedir

    def run(self, terms, variables=None, **kwargs):
        
        hostname = terms[0]
        
        if not isinstance(hostname, basestring):
            raise errors.AnsibleError("ip lookup expects a string (hostname)")
        
        return [socket.gethostbyname(hostname)]
```

Save this relative to your playbook as `lookup_plugins/ip.py`.

Then use it as `{{ lookup('ip', 'www.google.com') }}`

- [More about lookups](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_lookups.html)
- [(Not so much) More about creating lookup plugins](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/developing_plugins.html#lookup-plugins)

Comment: This is a great answer, but be aware that the lookup plugin API is changing significantly for 2.0, so your plugin would need to be rewritten to work in 2.0...

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, Matt. OT: Do you know what is the status of 2.0? I'm hot for the new features in there. The last thing I read was there should have been a beta release about a month ago. I worked with the devel branch for a while but it was too buggy and too dangerous to use at that time.

Comment: Thank you for the very informative answer, @udondan! This accomplishes exactly what I need. As a side note, I'd like to mention a response that I received on "usenet". I was pointed to this dig-based and very flexible lookup plugin: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/lookup/dig.py

Comment: udondan: the 2.0 alpha just dropped a few days ago (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ansible-devel/3e1pohu1XlQ) - there have been (and continue to be) a lot of changes and bugfixes, so the engineering team's not committing publicly to dates... Do try it out in your test environments though- it's definitely getting stable enough for most day-to-day uses.

Comment: For Python 3, replace `basestring` with `str`.

Answer (score 2):

The lookup plugin udondan mentions is the "right" way to do this (though the API changes for 2.0, so be aware of what version you're targeting if you go that way). If you just want something quick and dirty though, the following should work:

```
- hosts: yourhosts
  tasks:
  - local_action: shell dig +short host-to-lookup-here.com
    changed_when: false
    register: dig_output

  - set_fact:
      looked_up_ips: "{{ dig_output.stdout_lines }}"

  - debug: msg="found ip {{ item }}"
    with_items: looked_up_ips
```

The fact looked_up_ips would then be a list of the mapped IPs accessible from a template or whatever you need to use it in...

Comment: Thank you, @Matt Davis! I hacked up something similar by delegating the actual lookup to a shell script but this was taking me further away from the concept that I am preaching to others. That is why I was looking for more Ansible/Pythonic way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness' sake, apparently we've been shipping a dig lookup plugin in the box since around 1.9 that would wrap this up nicely (h/t Duncan Hutty):

https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/lookup/dig.py

Answer (score 1):

As @nitzmahone suggested, the [`dig`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/dig.html) plugin can be used exactly for this purpose. E.g.:

```
- name: Simple A record (IPV4 address) lookup for example.com
  debug: msg="{{ lookup('dig', 'example.com.')}}"
```

Prints

```
MSG:

  93.184.216.34
```

**Note**: you have to have `dnspython` installed in order for this to work. You can install it with

```
pip install dnspython
```